# Why postgresql pg_dump exports a view as a table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 `pg_dump` tool for extracting only the public schema definition using:

```
pg_dump -s -n public -h host -U postgres --dbname=db > ./schema.sql
```

but when I check `schema.sql` one of our views appears in a `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of a `CREATE VIEW` statement.

But, if I `pg_dump` the specific view using:

```
pg_dump -s -t myview -h host -U postgres --dbname=db > ./schema.sql
```

then `schema.sql` contains the actual view definition.

So, why is this happening? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 14):

Internally, a view is just a table with a rule, so this makes sense.

See here: https://postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rules-views.html

> Views in PostgreSQL are implemented using the rule system. In fact,
>   there is essentially no difference between:
>
> ```
> CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT * FROM mytab;
> ```
>
> compared against the two commands:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE myview (same column list as mytab);
> CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO myview DO INSTEAD
>     SELECT * FROM mytab;
> ```
>
> because this is exactly what the `CREATE VIEW` command does internally.
>   This has some side effects. One of them is that the information about
>   a view in the PostgreSQL system catalogs is exactly the same as it is
>   for a table. So for the parser, there is absolutely no difference
>   between a table and a view. They are the same thing: relations.